# post and get on Index controller laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js

Im having a problem when I make a get request to the index controller, the idea is that when I post to the index controller it returns only the 'comentarios' where bible_id is equal to the request,

Routes:

```
Route::resource('/comentarios', 'ComentariosController', ['except' => ['store']]);
Route::post('/comentarios ', 'ComentariosController@index');
Route::post('/newComentario', 'ComentariosController@new');
```

Request:

centralComponent.vue

```
passBibleId(bibleId) {
        this.bibleId = ''
        this.bibleId = bibleId
        console.log(bibleId)
        this.showModal = true

        await axios.post('/comentarios', {bibleId: this.bibleId}).then((response)=> {
            const comentario = response.data;
            console.log('posted', comentario)
        });
    }
```

comentComponent.vue

```
await axios.get('/comentarios').then( (response) => {
                console.log('get', response.data)
                this.comentarios = response.data;
            })
```

Controller:

```
public function index(Request $request)
    {

        $bibleID = $request->bibleId;



        
        return comentarios::where('user_id', Auth::id())->where('bible_id', $bibleID)->get();
    }
```

Currently if I remove the where from the controller, it shows me all the data from the database, if I change the controller's where condition to `return comentarios::where('user_id', Auth::id())->where('bible_id', 1)->get();`
it shows me the correct data.

The issue its when y use it like these

```
return comentarios::where('user_id', Auth::id())->where('bible_id', $bibleID)->get();
```

in my browser network the post has data but the get is empty.

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are not passing parameter with the request `await axios.get('/comentarios')`. It should look like

```
await axios.get('/comentarios', this.bibleID).then( (response) => {
            console.log('get', response.data)
            this.comentarios = response.data;
        })
```

Inyour controller you are trying to retrieve bibleID `$bibleID = $request->bibleId;` which is coming empty.

Comment: are you talking about the request get?currently if i 
`return $ request-> bibleId;`
 it returns the id that I am sending by the request post.
what I am trying to do is that at the time of the request get it brings me "filtered" by the bibleId

Comment: YES the get request. Also you are getting the bibleID on post request because you are passing it with the request`await axios.post('/comentarios', {bibleId: this.bibleId})`. Each time you sent GET and POST requests you are hitting 2 different routes. So if I understand you, after the post request you want to return the newly added record as response.

Comment: `Route::post('/comentarios ', 'ComentariosController@index');
Route::post('/newComentario', 'ComentariosController@new');`  This is little bit confusing . You have 2 routes with POST. It is not clear which does what. You already have resource controller, you could use it to return all comments with `index method`, to store comment with `store method` and so on...

Comment: About the `Route::post('/newComentario', 'ComentariosController@new');` its the sore, I left it like that just because I was testing, but does it influence something?

Comment: No, it doesn't but `Route::post('/comentarios ', 'ComentariosController@index')`  will, because the resource controller `method index` handles get request. If you want to store just use the `store method` and make sure to enable it by removing `, ['except' => ['store']]`. AGAIN , if I understand you, after the post(saving record) request you want to return the newly added record as response.